# PHP array sum not adding up all items

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code that I am using to try and calculate the sum of "amountReceived" column. The total for invID '95' should = 312, but for some reason it is only = 300. I am not sure what the issue is. (please see the DB images below).

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT amountReceived FROM payments WHERE invID='".$id."'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$totalPayment = array_sum($result);
$balanceDue = $invoiceTotal - $totalPayment;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because you only fetched one row...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well the mysql_fetch_array($sql) returns an array containing all "columns" of one row you fetched, means you get an e.g. array('amountReceived'=>150)

this should work:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT amountReceived FROM payments WHERE invID='".$id."'");
$totalPayment = 0;
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $totalPayment += $result['amountReceived'];
}
$balanceDue = $invoiceTotal - $totalPayment;
```

this is just a php side description of the problem, if you want to be more efficient, use [sel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457638/sel)'s version ;)

Comment: It would be much more efficient to use the aggregate functions within the database to get the totals needed.

Answer (score 7):

How about using SUM()?

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amountReceived) FROM payments WHERE invID='".$id."'");
$totalPayment = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
```

Comment: I tried this before and it is not working. I am just not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `mysql_*` functions - use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).
2. `print_r($result);` to see if there's something inside.

Comment: Don't forget you can inline code highlight with the backticks (`) and link to useful resources